# Magento block and layout confusion

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm new in Magento. Now im trying to understand how blocks and layouts working. Here is my layout file `

```
<layout>
    <custom_index_getallfaq>
        <reference name="head">
                <action method="setTitle">
                    <arg>All FAQ's</arg>
                </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="custom/type" name="root" template="view.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </custom_index_getallfaq>

    <custom_index_addnewfaq>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle">
                <arg>All FAQ's</arg>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="custom/type" name="root" template="form.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </custom_index_addnewfaq>
</layout>`
```

First handler working properly. It displaying template view.phtml
    The problem is second handler working unexpected for me. It displaying index page of my site instead of form.phtml
Thank you for help